# Annotation field is str instead of datetime.datetime

Tags: python, django, mysql-python, django-annotate, django-mysql

## Example

I'm trying to annotate objects using data from a related model's `DateTimeField`.

```py
    class Author(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Book(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        is_published = models.BooleanField()
        publication_date = models.DateTimeField()
        author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    queryset = Author.objects.annotate(
        has_unpublished=Exists(
            Book.objects.filter(
                author=OuterRef('pk'),
                is_published=False))
    ).annotate(
        last_published_date=Max(
            'book__publication_date',
            filter=Q(book__is_published=True)
        )
    )
```

I alternate between the default local `sqlite3` database and `MySQL` (with `mysqlclient`). SQLite works and MySQL crashes.

Here's the reason: compilers for both databases

```py
results = compiler.execute_sql(**kwargs)
```

return a list of lists of tuples of int and string, like so:

**SQLite**

```py
<class 'list'>: [[(1, 'Alice', 1, '2017-01-01 01:00:00'), (2, 'Bob', 0, '2019-01-05 13:00:00'), (3, 'Carol', 1, None), (4, 'Dan', 0, None)]]
```

**MySQL**

```py
<class 'list'>: [((1, 'Alice', 1, '2017-01-01 01:00:00.000000'), (2, 'Bob', 0, '2019-01-05 13:00:00.000000'), (3, 'Carol', 1, None), (4, 'Dan', 0, None))]
```

Now, when the SQLite backend sees a supposed datetime field, it generates a converter at runtime using this method:

**django.db.backends.sqlite3.operations.DatabaseOperations**

```py
    def convert_datetimefield_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is not None:
            if not isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
                value = parse_datetime(value)
            if settings.USE_TZ and not timezone.is_aware(value):
                value = timezone.make_aware(value, self.connection.timezone)
        return value
```

which works ok.

The MySQL backend, however, does this:

**django.db.backends.mysql.operations.DatabaseOperations**

```py
    def convert_datetimefield_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is not None:
            value = timezone.make_aware(value, self.connection.timezone)
        return value
```

Django then proceeds to crash trying to check an `<str>` for timezone awareness.

## Context

The above is a toy example I used to reproduce the crash.

In our actual production environment, the MySQL compiler's `execute_sql`, bizarrely, returns a list of lists of tuples of "raw" data with `datetime.datetime` objects if I request a full list of annotated authors (`action=='list'`), and the same list with a string if I request a particular one (`action=='retrieve'`). The querysets' respective sql queries only differ by the presence of a single WHERE clause.

This leads me to think I'm doing something wrong and not getting the raw `datetime.datetime` I'm supposed to get from the driver (rather than the far lower probability of a bug in Django).

What should I do? N+1 is out of the question, this will be the app's main operator view and the datetime field is actually *two* one-to-many relationships deep.